# Transform table into smaller table (animation)

Tags: python, manim

I wrote a short animation in Manim library, that first highlight two rows and then transform the table into a smaller one only with these two rows. I'm using the following lib versions:

- python 3.10.7
- manim 0.17.2

  ```
   from manim import *

   # creeate map dictionary
   map = {"SELECT" : GOLD, "FROM" : GOLD, "WHERE" : GOLD}

   class tablesSelect(Scene):
       def construct(self):
           origin_data = [["Pavel", "23", "pavel@seznam.cz"],
            ["Radim", "21", "radim@gmail.com"],
            ["Jane", "22", "jane@yahoo.com"],
            ["Mike", "20", "mike@post.com"]]
           column_labels1 = [Text("Name"), Text("Age"), Text("Email")]
           # create a table with 3 columns and 4 rows that is 20 units wide and 10 units tall
           table1 = Table(
               table = origin_data,
               col_labels=column_labels1)
           table1.set_width(5)  # set the width of the table
           table1.move_to(ORIGIN)  # set the position of the table to the center of the screen
           for i in range(0,3):
               table1.add_highlighted_cell((1, i), color=BLUE) # highlight the first row

           table2 = table1.copy()
           for i in range(0,3):
               table2.add_highlighted_cell((2, i), color=RED) # highlight the first row
           for i in range(0,3):
               table2.add_highlighted_cell((4, i), color=RED) # highlight the first row

           filtered_data = [row for row in origin_data if int(row[1]) > 21]
           column_labels2 = [Text("Name"), Text("Age"), Text("Email")]
           table3 = Table(
               table = filtered_data,
               col_labels=column_labels2)
           table3.set_width(5)  # set the width of the table
           table3.move_to(ORIGIN)  # set the position of the table to the center of the screen
           for i in range(0,3):
               table3.add_highlighted_cell((1, i), color=BLUE) # highlight the first row
           for i in range(0,3):
               table3.add_highlighted_cell((2, i), color=RED) # highlight the second row
           for i in range(0,3):
               table3.add_highlighted_cell((3, i), color=RED) # highlight the third row


           self.play(Create(table1))  # show the table on the screen
           self.wait(2)  # wait for 2 seconds
           self.play(TransformMatchingShapes(table1, table2))
           self.wait(2)  # wait for 2 seconds
           self.play(TransformMatchingShapes(table2, table3))
           self.wait(2)  # wait for 2 seconds`

   with tempconfig({"quality": "medium_quality", "preview": True}):
       scene = tablesSelect()
       scene.render()
  ```

I have two questions regarding the code:

1. I was unable to do the transitions just updating one `Table` object, therefore, I create three tables for each transition. Is this a correct approach?
2. The third table is created from scratch. Is there a way to remove two rows from table data if I create a copy of the second table?

Any other comments to the code are welcomed.